# Enable/Disable button based on checkbox input via GroupBox

Tags: winforms, vb.net-2010

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to enable/disable a button when at least one checkbox is checked in each group box.

Comment: I assume this is Winforms?

Comment: Could you paste some code or any attempts you have made? It helps on StackOverflow if you provide some workings that you have done so people can point you in the right direction